# How to create an object of a class having protected constructor?

Tags: c++

I am facing an issue while writing unit test cases for a source file. In this file lets say file A.cpp need to create object of class B(B.cpp) having protected constructor.

class B is part of some library and path of that is set in env variable.
While including the header i am not getting any error but moment i go for object creation getting following error.

**UdrEventHandlerTest.C:480: error: 'DbResponseEvent' was not declared in this scope error.**

I have tried following things to fix this but no luck:

1. Including class B header file in test file(A.h)
2. forward declaring class B in class A.
3. Deriving class B from Test class A.

Any help is appreciated ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make the test class a friend of the class-under-test.

Comment: when you need help with an error in your code you should post the code an the error message. Inheriting from the class should work. See also [mcve]

Comment: Error : In Test file compilation 

UdrEventHandlerTest.C: In member function 'void UdrEventHandlerTest::testCreateStateResultInd()':
UdrEventHandlerTest.C:480: error: 'DbResponseEvent' was not declared in this scope

Test file : UdrEventHandlerTest.C +480
Exg::auto_ptr<DbResponseEvent> temdbrespEvt(new DbResponseEvent(StackEvent::EventPriority_2,StackEvent::Green))

In test File : UdrEventHandlerTest.C I want to create an object of a class DbResponseEvent. The object of class DbResponseEvent will used to create dummy input for source file function (UdrEventHandler.C).